# Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns false on Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to check whether external storage is available or even I think I made all correct it still says storage is not available.

```
    private String state;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.externaldata);
        eWrite = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tveWrite);
        eRead = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tveRead);
        enviromentState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();        
if (enviromentState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    // read and write
                    eWrite.setText("you can write");
                    eRead.setText("you can read");
                } else if (enviromentState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
                    // read but cant write
                    eWrite.setText("you cannot write ");
                    eRead.setText("but you can read");
                } else {
                    eWrite.setText("you cannot write");
                    eRead.setText("you canot read");
                }
    }
```

and I also gave permissions on AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

here screen shot of my virtual device.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Is the "virtual device" an emulator? Did you configure an SD card on it?

Comment: are you working in Windows? I remember that at one time I needed to give permissions to the user that was running Eclipse to the path where the emulator was running on the OS as well

Comment: yes I did configure sd card on it. and I am working on Mac OSX mountain lion.

Comment: can you show how you set environmetState in your code sample? Also, can you browse to it via adb? e.g. 'adb shell' followed by 'cd mnt/sdcard'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem by expanding SD Card size to **151mb**

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come by this number?

Comment: been a while but if I remember correctly I just increased default 150 by 1 :p

Comment: Ah. That explains it. My default was 100, which made me wonder.

Comment: Life saver. Never would have figured this out on my own. Thanks a lot!